# Canceling form submission within channel_form_entry_form_tagdata_start hook handler in 2.7+

Tags: channel-form

I am using this hook `channel_form_entry_form_tagdata_start` to process some data before it is saved to database.

But there are many cases where I want to cancel. Validation errors, missing field, etc.

What is the correct way to this inside a hook event handler?

Am I even using the correct hook?

P.S.

I used this [technique](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/11738/is-it-possible-for-the-hook-handler-of-safecracker-submit-entry-start-to-cancel) before. Is this still the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the previous technique having same method call but the hook will be different `channel_form_submit_entry_start` instead of `safecracker_submit_entry_start`

**Please note**: if you are updating the hook name within the extension, it would be easy and good to uninstall it first and then update the hook name. Again install it.

I hope, everything would work fine for you.

Comment: It is a curious case that I have. It seems that the technique that we used only stops the submission and creation of safecracker registration channels. But it does not stop the creation of a member.

Comment: I think, you are using "Safecracker Registration" module. Not sure, why this module not respecting this hook. Also, it seems that "Safecracker Registration" doesn't have any extension hook.

Comment: Those Safecracker hooks are suppose to be inherited and not break in 2.7. I am going to be re-releasing this module under the name "Channel Registration". I need to get rid of the "Safecracker" ties. That's the reason it hasn't been updated, it because it required a fairly significant rewrite. It works 100% on my end, just doesn't use those new Channel Form hooks yet.

Comment: @JustinKimbrell Safecracker Registration is not inserting the channel data if there are some problems like validation errors. That is correct behavior. The problem that I have is that the member data is inserted regardless of errors. This does not necessarily mean that it is Safecracker Registration's fault. It might be EE. That is why I asked.

Comment: Interesting. I have not seen that on my end. The error handling and member registration works 100% on my end, so this might be a specific EE 2.7 issue.